# React context update and API calls in consuming component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

So I have my React component hierarchy as below in App.js

```
<MyContextProvider>
<HeaderComponent>
<Route path="/path1">
<SomeComp1 />
</Route>
</MyContextProvider>
```

Now in my HeaderComponent, I set my context value. For some scenarios, it is set twice - Once via the API call and second, after that component is loaded (based on some cookie)

So I kind of override that context value from API call by the local cookie value (only if cookie exists)

Now the issue is in "SomeComp1", I consume this context and have some generic code which makes some API calls using the context value in it's path param.
Since the context is updated twice, I see the calls being made twice in SomeComp1

What is the best way to handle this scenario? Basically, I want only one API call to be made in my consuming component (i.e. SomeComp1)

So My SomeComp1 looks like below (only the relevant code shown)

```
const [contextData] = React.useContext(MyContext);
const [stateString1, setStateString1] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
setStateString1(contextData.stateString1);
}, [contextData.stateString1])

useEffect(()=>{
let url = "http://someURL/${stateString1}";
fetch(url);
}, [stateString1])
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please add a part of code that makes a call to the API from SomeComp1?

Comment: @MilaA - Added relevant code

Comment: posted an answer, I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

*I suppose the call is done into the useEffect of the `<SomeComponent/>` component.*

What if you track number of renders/name of type the current value is based on.

In `Context`, for example, create something like:

```
initialState = {
  fetched : false
};

const [fetched, setFetched ] = useState( initialState.fetched );
```

and in `<SomeComponent1/>`:

```
const { fetched, setFetched } = useContext( yourContextHere );


useEffect( () => {
  if ( fetched ) {
    return;
  }  
  axios.post.....then( () => {
    setFetched( true )
  } )
}, [] );
```

---

With your updated code it would be something like:

```
const [ apiCalled, setApiCalled ] = useState( false )
const [contextData] = React.useContext(MyContext);
const [stateString1, setStateString1] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
setStateString1(contextData.stateString1);
}, [contextData.stateString1])

useEffect(()=>{
if ( apiCalled ) {
  return;
}
let url = "http://someURL/${stateString1}";
fetch(url).then( () => { setApiCalled( true ) } );
}, [stateString1])
```

### Why to create such a "helper" variable

Your `stateString1 is undefined by default and we cannot limit useEffect` to only be called on initial render.

That is why we have to leave the dependency array like `[stateString1]` but keep count of if we have called API already or no, in a separate variable.

---

**STORE THAT VARIABLE IN CONTEXT IF COMPONENT OCCASIONALLY GETS REMOVED FROM THE DOM.**

**OTHERWISE, STORE IT DIRECTLY IN COMPONENT**

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, if `<SomeComp1 />` depends on `MyContext` then it is completely valid for it to re-render as often as it changes.

So instead of preventing, or working around that, you need to change `<SomeComp1 />`'s dependencies. For example:

- make it depend on some other context value or property for which it is ok to re-render when it changes,
- introduce a signal that indicates that the value is not ready yet, and as such `<SomeComp1 />` should not render at all (or render a fallback).

For example (in hopes that this abstract is sufficient):

```
<MyContextProvider>        //- current context
  <ExtraContextProvider>   //- new context, defaults to null (the signal)
    <HeaderComponent>      //- consumes MyContext
                           //  does it's thing with regards to cookies
                           //  and only after that sets ExtraContext to the final value
    <Route path="/path1">
      <SomeComp1/>         //- consumes ExtraContext
                           //  but renders fallback (or nothing) as when it's null
    </Route>
  </ExtraContextProvider>
</MyContextProvider>
```

---

Alternatively the same could be done with only one context, by including the signal in it's value.

For example: `MyContext` could be `{someValue: string; ready: bool}` with some  initial value like `{someValue: 'foo'; ready: false}`.

- `<HeaderComponent>` will consume that value, and maybe update it, but will set `ready: true` after it's done.
- `<SomeComp1/>` will, like above, only render when `ready === true`, and in that case use `someValue` for it's work.

---

On a side note, your effect in `<SomeComp1/>` is a bit redundant, it could be simply:

```
const [contextData] = React.useContext(MyContext);

useEffect(()=>{
  let url = `http://someURL/${contextData.stateString1}`;
  fetch(url);
}, [contextData.stateString1]);
```